Filter Price using Slider in ASP.NET CORE
I'm trying to do price filtering with slider bar. The view will be like this . I using ajax to filltering the price. Here the code of slider and product view :
<div class="price-filter">
    <div id="price-slider"></div>
        <div class="input-number price-min">
                <input id="price-min" type="number">
                <span class="qty-up">+</span>
                <span class="qty-down">-</span>
        </div>
                <span>-</span>
                <div class="input-number price-max">
                    <input id="price-max" type="number">
                    <span class="qty-up">+</span>
                    <span class="qty-down">-</span>
                </div>
</div>
//product 
<div id="store" class="col-md-9">
<div class="row">
                <!-- product -->
                @foreach (var item in Model.Take(6))
                {
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="product">
                            <a href="/post/@SlugGenerator.SlugGenerator.GenerateSlug(item.ProductName)-@item.ProductItems.FirstOrDefault().ProductVariations.FirstOrDefault().ProductVarId" />
                            <div class="product-img">

                                <img src="~/Contents/img/@item.ProductItems.FirstOrDefault().Image1" width="200" height="200" alt="">
                                    <div class="product-label">
                                        <span class="sale">-30%</span>
                                        <span class="new">NEW</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-body">
                                @*  <p class="product-category">@item.Category.CategoryName.ToUpper()</p> *@
                                    <h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">@item.ProductName.ToUpper()</a></h3>
                                    <h4 class="product-price">$@item.Price<del class="product-old-price">@* $@(item.Product.Price + 200) *@</del></h4>
                                    <div class="product-rating">
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-btns">
                                        <button class="add-to-wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i><span class="tooltipp">add to wishlist</span></button>
                                        <button class="add-to-compare"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i><span class="tooltipp">add to compare</span></button>
                                        <button class="quick-view"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="tooltipp">quick view</span></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                <!-- /product -->
 </div>
</div>

The ajax code so its can filtering the product by price without reloading the page :
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#price-slider").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 100000,
            max: 2000000,
            values: [100000, 2000000],
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#price-min").val(ui.values[0]);
                $("#price-max").val(ui.values[1]);
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                var min = ui.values[0];
                var max = ui.values[1];
                var cateid = $('#category-id').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("FilterByPrice", "ProductView")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { minPrice: min, maxPrice: max, categoryId: cateid },
                    success: function (productlist) {
                        var newproductrow = "";
                        $.each(productlist, function (index, item) {
                            newproductrow += '<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">';
                            newproductrow += '<div class="product">';
                            newproductrow += '<a href="/post/' + item.SlugGenerator.SlugGenerator.GenerateSlug(item.ProductName) + '-' + item.ProductItems[0].ProductVariations[0].ProductVarId + '">';
                            newproductrow += '<div class="product-img">';
                            newproductrow += '<img src="~/Contents/img/' + item.ProductItems[0].Image1 + '" width="200" height="200" alt="">';
                            newproductrow += '<div class="product-label">';
                            newproductrow += '<span class="sale">-30%</span>';
                            newproductrow += '<span class="new">NEW</span>';
                            newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close product-label
                            newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close product-img
                            newproductrow += '<div class="product-body">';
                            newproductrow += '<h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">' + item.ProductName.toUpperCase() + '</a></h3>';
                            newproductrow += '<h4 class="product-price">$' + item.Price + '<del class="product-old-price">$' + (item.Price + 200) + '</del></h4>';
                            newproductrow += '<div class="product-rating">';
                            newproductrow += '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
                            newproductrow += '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
                            newproductrow += '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
                            newproductrow += '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
                            newproductrow += '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
                            newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close product-rating
                            newproductrow += '<div class="product-btns">';
                            newproductrow += '<button class="add-to-wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i><span class="tooltipp">add to wishlist</span></button>';
                            newproductrow += '<button class="add-to-compare"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i><span class="tooltipp">add to compare</span></button>';
                            newproductrow += '<button class="quick-view"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="tooltipp">quick view</span></button>';
                            newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close product-btns
                            newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close product-body
                            newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close product
                            newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close col-md-4
                        });

                        $("#store .row").html(newproductrow);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>

The controller filting the price :
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult FilterByPrice(int minPrice, int maxPrice, int categoryId)
{

    var filteredProducts = _context.Products
        .Where(p => p.Price >= minPrice && p.Price <= maxPrice && p.CategoryId == categoryId)
        .ToList();

    
    return new JsonResult(filteredProducts);
}

But when I'm adjust on that bar there is nothing happened. I open the network and choose Fetch/XHR, I saw there is a json returned img when I ajust the bar. The json return :
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$values": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "productId": 8,
            "productName": "POSEE",
            "categoryId": 4,
            "price": 400000,
            "description": null,
            "brand": 5,
            "brandNavigation": null,
            "category": null,
            "productItems": {
                "$id": "3",
                "$values": []
            }
        },
        {
            "$id": "4",
            "productId": 9,
            "productName": "ShondoHCM",
            "categoryId": 4,
            "price": 500000,
            "description": null,
            "brand": 11,
            "brandNavigation": null,
            "category": null,
            "productItems": {
                "$id": "5",
                "$values": []
            }
        },
        {
            "$id": "6",
            "productId": 10,
            "productName": "BITIS",
            "categoryId": 4,
            "price": 800000,
            "description": null,
            "brand": 4,
            "brandNavigation": null,
            "category": null,
            "productItems": {
                "$id": "7",
                "$values": []
            }
        }
    ]
}

Anyone know the problem why the product not showing according to price ? I believed this is about the for loop. I really appreciate any instruction. Thank you

Please use a partial view and put your for loop logic in that. Then use AJAX to update its html.

Most likely the error is because you are using PascalCase properties in jQuery code, and JSON received in camelCase. to fix it change your script to:
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#price-slider").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 100000,
        max: 2000000,
        values: [100000, 2000000],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#price-min").val(ui.values[0]);
            $("#price-max").val(ui.values[1]);
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var min = ui.values[0];
            var max = ui.values[1];
            var cateid = $('#category-id').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("FilterByPrice", "ProductView")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { minPrice: min, maxPrice: max, categoryId: cateid },
                success: function (productlist) {
                    var newproductrow = "";
                    $.each(productlist, function (index, item) {
                        newproductrow += '<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">';
                        newproductrow += '<div class="product">';
                        newproductrow += '<a href="/post/' + item.SlugGenerator.SlugGenerator.GenerateSlug(item.productName) + '-' + item.productItems[0].productVariations[0].productVarId + '">';
                        newproductrow += '<div class="product-img">';
                        newproductrow += '<img src="~/Contents/img/' + item.productItems[0].image1 + '" width="200" height="200" alt="">';
                        newproductrow += '<div class="product-label">';
                        newproductrow += '<span class="sale">-30%</span>';
                        newproductrow += '<span class="new">NEW</span>';
                        newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close product-label
                        newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close product-img
                        newproductrow += '<div class="product-body">';
                        newproductrow += '<h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">' + item.productName.toUpperCase() + '</a></h3>';
                        newproductrow += '<h4 class="product-price">$' + item.price + '<del class="product-old-price">$' + (item.price + 200) + '</del></h4>';
                        newproductrow += '<div class="product-rating">';
                        newproductrow += '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
                        newproductrow += '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
                        newproductrow += '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
                        newproductrow += '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
                        newproductrow += '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
                        newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close product-rating
                        newproductrow += '<div class="product-btns">';
                        newproductrow += '<button class="add-to-wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i><span class="tooltipp">add to wishlist</span></button>';
                        newproductrow += '<button class="add-to-compare"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i><span class="tooltipp">add to compare</span></button>';
                        newproductrow += '<button class="quick-view"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="tooltipp">quick view</span></button>';
                        newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close product-btns
                        newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close product-body
                        newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close product
                        newproductrow += '</div>'; // Close col-md-4
                    });

                    $("#store .row").html(newproductrow);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

Also this line will throw an error:
newproductrow += '<a href="/post/' + item.SlugGenerator.SlugGenerator.GenerateSlug(item.productName) + '-' + item.productItems[0].productVariations[0].productVarId + '">';

it's better to call SlugGenerator.GenerateSlug in backend as below:
[HttpGet]

public async Task FilterByPrice(int minPrice, int maxPrice, int categoryId)
{
var filteredProducts = await _context.Products
    .Where(p => p.Price >= minPrice && p.Price <= maxPrice && p.CategoryId == categoryId)
    .Select(m => new ProductView
    {
        Brand = m.Brand,
        BrandNavigation = m.BrandNavigation,
        Category = m.Category,
        CategoryId = categoryId,
        Description = m.Description,
        Id = m.Id,
        Price = m.Price,
        ProductId = m.ProductId,
        ProductItems = m.ProductItems,
        ProductName = m.ProductName,
        //Here to generate SlugName using SlugGenerator (Note that method must be static)
        SlugName = Item.SlugGenerator.GenerateSlug(m.ProductName),
    })
    .ToListAsync();

return new JsonResult(filteredProducts);

}
and in jQuery change the line to
newproductrow += '<a href="/post/' + item.slugName + '">';

